# python, import file under current folder from a file under other directory

Tags: python

I have a package which intends to import a file that user (me) provides

In **c:\lib**\calc.py

```
# some codes to find which file to import
filename = "A"
__import__(filename)
...
```

And I have a file **c:\scripts**\A.py

Note A.py is in a different folder than calc.py. Now I'm supposed to do this under command window

```
cd C:\scripts
python c:\lib\calc.py
```

but I get an error message

```
No module named A
```

A.py is in the current folder, why does python fail to find it? How can I make A.py available?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using `__import__` instead of just `import A` ? What's in your `sys.path`?

Comment: You can add the `scripts` directory to your PYTHONPATH environment variable.

Comment: "A" is only known under run time. I simplified the code a bit, the actual command is something like "python c:\lib\calc.py --file A.py"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the path to your scripts directory in your script calc.py so it can find the A.py module.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('C:\scripts')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Python version 2.7 or newer you can use the [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html) package. The `import_module` function can accept an absolute path which, IIRC, does not need to be on your PYTHONPATH.

```
import importlib
mod = importlib.import_module(filepath)
```

Or, if you wanted to manually do the work yourself (or if you are using Python 2.6 or earlier), you can use the [`imp`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html) package directly:

```
import imp
mod = imp.load_module(imp.find_module(filename, filepath))
```